# Objective C Resize UIImage with Interpolation Error

Tags: ios, uiimage, interpolation

I'm trying to have interpolate this image when resizing, yet I keep getting this error. What is the correct form for using Interpolationquality?
[image: [![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN45w.png)

Comment: Where can we find the declaration of the `ASConvenienceMethods` class?

Comment: Also, edit your question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like interpolationQuality wasn't an proper parameter. I figured out that CMD+clicking on the method gives the proper parameters you can use :)